# How to access web.config key in JavaScript without using .aspx page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I'm trying to access a web.config key in JavaScript, but don't want to add code to a .aspx file. Here's my code:

Web.config file:

```
<add key="key" value="password"/>
```

JavaScript file:

```
var param = '<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"].ToString() %>';
```

Thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it's under `appSettings`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access `web.config` or any serverside related data from `js` files directly. You can assign all data you want to access from client on .aspx mester page to `window` object and then access it in `js` files.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, that is exactly how I do it, see below my sample code from my old web.forms project.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var googleAnalyticsTrackingEnabled = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAnalyticsTrackingEnabled"].ToString() %>';

    if (googleAnalyticsTrackingEnabled.toLowerCase() == 'true') {

// DO WHATEVER

    }

</script>
```

And this is the key value in my web.config for my case;

```
<configuration>
...
<appSettings>
  ...
  <!--Google Analytics settings-->
  <add key="GoogleAnalyticsTrackingEnabled" value="true" />
  ...
</appSettings>
...
</configuration>
```